# How can the common code written in an abstract class be a little dependent of an inherited class property?

Tags: c#, abstract

A small example to illustrate my question: I write a program that accesses a database. Most of the properties and methods are the same for every table. Therefore I try to use an abstract class. To delete, insert or update a row, no problem. But to retrieve rows, the Dml statement is different from table to table (here ??? should be replaced by the name of the table, but it is not always so trivial).

What solution?

Thank you,

Gilbert

```
public abstract class SQLiteAbstractTable
{
    #region Properties (DB columns)
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatCreation { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatMaj { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    public static int Delete<T>(int pId)
    {
        int n = CgtDataSQLite.Cn.Delete<T>(pId);
        return n;
    }
    // Called by : var LstEnr = SQLiteAbstractTable.GetLstInstance<SQLiteReference>();
    public static List<T> GetLstInstance<T>() where T : SQLiteAbstractTable, new()
    {
        var LstEnr = CgtDataSQLite.Cn.Query<T>("SELECT * FROM ???");
        return LstEnr;
    }

    public int Insert()
    {
        int n = CgtDataSQLite.Cn.Insert(this);
        return n;
    }

    public int Update()
    {
        int n = CgtDataSQLite.Cn.Update(this);
        return n;
    }
    #endregion
}

[Table("Reference")]
public class SQLiteReference : SQLiteAbstractTable
{
    #region Properties (additional DB columns)
    [MaxLength(8)] public string DatPublication { get; set; }
    [NotNull, MaxLength(80)] public string Nom { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public SQLiteReference()
    {
    }

    public SQLiteReference(int id, int typeReferenceId, string datPublication, string nom, string nomAbrege, string url = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        DatPublication = datPublication;
        Nom = nom;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Have a property `protected abstract string Query`, then in each subclass override this property to the query you need. In `GetLstInstance` use this property. Not ideal, since you have to repeat "SELECT ... " every time, but it's the simplest

Comment: GetLstInstance is a static method so you can not pass value to it from a inherited class. You need to make this method non static and have query property abstracted as suggested by Alex.